# Tiered NSPopupButton binding

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nspopupbutton

I'm trying to have two NSPopupButton that are linked to each other and am having issues with the bindings on the 'child' button.

I have three Core Data entity types:  `Order`, `Client`, and `Station`.  `Station` -> `Client` is a many-to-1, so a `Client` has multiple `Station`, but a `Station` can only point to one client.

An `Order` has a single `Station` attached to it, so I created all the bindings like I show below.  I can properly pick any client from the first dropdown, but then the stations dropdown just shows the currently selected station.  I don't see all the stations available, and if I change the client, I don't see a new list of stations to choose from.

**Order Controller**

An NSObjectController bound to the `order` entity property in the view controller.

**Clients Array Controller**

Just binds to the view controller's managedObjectContext to get all clients.

**Stations Array Controller**

[image] [image]

**Client NSPopupButton**

[image: Content Binding] [image: Content Values Binding] [image: Selected Index Binding]

**Station NSPopupButton**

[image: Station Dropdown Content Binding] [image: Station Dropdown Content Values Binding] [image: Station Dropdown Selected Object Binding]

Comment: What is the relation between order and client?

Comment: Is the content of the order controller an order or a client?

Comment: Sorry, the order controller has an order.  client was a typo.    An order is for a specific station, and that station belongs to a client.  Think of it as radio stations.  You have multiple stations all owned by a parent company (the client)

Comment: Does the order have a client property?

Comment: No. Order has a station property, which in turn has a client property. Because a station belongs to a client it doesn't have to store client as well. But when a human edits via the UI they have to pick a client first because station names may not be unique, even though they have a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected value of the client popup button is used to filter the stations, it shouldn't change the client of the station of the order. Bind Selected index (instead of Selected Object) of the client popup button to the Client Array Controller, Controller Key `selectionIndex`, no Model Key Path.

Bind Selected Object of the station popup button to the Order Object Controller, Controller Key `selection`, Model Key Path `station`.

When the user selects a client, the selected station is still the station of the order. If this station has a different client, the station popup button doesn't automagically select another station. You can fix this in the action of the client popup button. For example:

```
- (IBAction)clientAction:(id)sender {
    NSArray *stations = self.stationArrayController.arrangedObjects;
    if (![stations containsObject:order.station]) {
        if (stations.count > 0)
            self.order.station = stations[0];
        else
            self.order.station = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as I select a client the clientAction is called, and at that point the stationArrayController has not yet populated with the new values apparently.

Comment: Weird, in my test app the popup button first updates the bindings and then calls the action method.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. I updated the question to show my current bindings.  When I'm running now I get an exception about NSCFNumber count not recognized.  It looks like it's just failing to do the initial bindings now.

Comment: Remove the Selected Indexes binding of the Stations Array Controller. You don't need it and it is binding a set to a number.

Comment: Thanks!  I also changed it to be ContentSet instead as per the error I was getting for the stations array.  My only piece left to solve is the initial values when I edit an existing order.  I can call `clientDropDown.selectItemWithTitle(order.stations.client.name)` in `viewDidLoad` and that sets properly, but the station array controller doesn't 'trigger' that an update was made, so my list of stations is wrong at that point still.

Comment: OK, got it all working now.  I switched to getting the indexOf the selected object from the array controller and then calling setSelectionIndex() on the array controller instead of setting based on the button.